# no GUI after upgrade to kubuntu 18.04 nvdia GeForce 840M strongly suspected

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, 18.04

I updated my kubuntu from 17.04 to 18.04 by updating to 17.10 and directly continuing to 18.04

After reboot Plasma didn't come up, but luckily via alt + F2 I get a bash.

I have a Dell Latitude E5450 with a Nvidia GeForce 840M, latter is a plain pain in the ass since I got this laptop. So I strongly suspect that it is the culprit this time, too.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

gives me

- nvidia-390 as recommended
- nvidia-340
- nouveau as open source driver

I tried all of them and every time I get stuck with a black screen and a cursor, which doesn't even blink.

How can I check if the culprit is really the graphics card (again....) or something else? Which log do I have to check?

And if it is in fact the graphic card, has someone ideas how to solve this mess?

This question seems to solve the problem for Gnome, but I use kde:
[No GUI after Kubuntu 18.04 LTS upgrade from 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029509/no-gui-after-kubuntu-18-04-lts-upgrade-from-17-10)

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install plasma-desktop
```

Hasn't got any effect.

Comment: have you tried nouveau.modeset=0  to grub when you boot?

Comment: What does it do and where exactly do I set this option?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem with nvidia drivers. After login to console check `journalctl -xb` and look on Xorg part of logs. If you have kernel 4.16 probably you should try to install v396.24 - downloadable from nvidia support site. Check what show
`dkms status`

Comment: dkms status output is nvidia, 390.48 4.15.0-20-generic

Comment: how exactly do I call jounal -xb?
I get a command "journal" not found

Comment: I downloaded the neweset driver from nvidia yeserday, but the installer stops with a stupid error like mentioned here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/798932/how-can-i-fix-unable-to-load-nvidia-installer-ncurses-v6-user-interface#824320

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be `journalctl -xb`

Comment: journalctl -xb
Gives me 
nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel
nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel
Disabliung lock debugging due to kernel taint
....
nvidia: module verfication failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Comment: Try to reinstall "nvidia-384" package (should be easiest than use dkms if you are new). You can purge them and then install again or use dkms to rebuild and reinstall modules.

Comment: no change, sorry.... 
I did sudo apt-get install nvidia-384 but nothing changed and the new driver isn't listed as an otion, when i do sudo ubuntu-drivers devices.

Why do you think nvidia-384 is better than 390?

Comment: so I managed to completely deinstall the nvidia driver  in a painful process and install the newest recommended one from the nvidia site. 390.48
Still the same: Black screen with a non-blinking cursor.
After more than 24hours I start to get desperate.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was a new install by shrinking my partition and install it on a new one fresh. And: Tadaaa.... 
I saw colours. Graphics.... and have to configure my huge load of applications again. Luckily I made a backup before.

So the upgrade performance was totally shitty, while the actual installation of the system worked. No clue why.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

still show the same output, but the GUI is present.

Sorry that I cannot give any more help other than: Don't upgrade, reinstall. Again upgrade it didn't work.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with your nvidia drivers.
I had the exact same problem; apparently, when you run kde / plasma, you end up with nothing when running the normal upgrade procedure.

I can't find back my history, but I think I ran the following in the end:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure plasma-desktop
$ sudo systemctl restart display-manager.service
```

After that you still have to select 'plasma' as desktop before logging in!
Also, then plasmashell crashed when I clicked a panel, but after ALT-F2 and typing 'plasmashell' that restarted again and then everything was ok.

Edit: added the second sudo command. I'm not 100% sure what I did, or what is needed; but if this helps someone then please add a comment ;).

Comment: What I did in the end was a complete reinstall. tabula rasa. 
Very annoying and depressing. If I had done the reinstall from the beginning I would have at least saved 2 days work, all unsaved data was gone anyway. 

Since it was not the first time that upgrading didn't work out I guess I will opt for the fresh install from now on. After an extensive backup of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try restart the plasmashell:
`kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell`

note: I use nvidia 440 proprietary driver on KDE Neon 20.04 using 'Performance Mode' PRIME profile in `nvidia-setting`